# Using Ruby to send notification to Firebase

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Ruby version 1.8.7.

I use this FCM gem https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm and want to send notification message to Android client app but it does not work.

In Controller:

```
fcm = FCM.new(FIREBASE_API_KEY, :timeout => 30)
 options = {:data => {:message => "This is a FCM Topic Message!"}}
 response = fcm.send_to_topic('global', options)
```

Class FCM:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'cgi'
require 'json'

class FCM
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm'
  default_timeout 30
  format :json

  attr_accessor :timeout, :api_key

  def initialize(api_key, client_options = {})
    @api_key = api_key
    @client_options = client_options
  end

  def send_with_notification_key(notification_key, options = {})
    body = { :to => notification_key }.merge(options)

    params = {
        :body => body.to_json,
        :headers => {
        'Authorization' => "key=#{@api_key}",
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }
  }

  response = self.class.post('/send', params.merge(@client_options))
  response.parsed_response
  end

  def send_to_topic(topic, options = {})
    if topic =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.~%]+/
        send_with_notification_key('/topics/' + topic, options)
    end
  end
end
```

1. The server key is correct, because I can send notification successfully by PHP code.
2. The response output as below:
   {"message_id"=>8885803884270587181}

Could anyone please to point out what wrong with the code. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do `params.to_json`

Comment: response = self.class.post('/send', params.merge(@client_options).to_json) produces error TypeError (can't convert String into Hash).

Comment: Your code works. There is no error message. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: The `FCM` class is part of the the FCM gem. It's unlikely that there's the problem.

Comment: My android client app does not receive any notification

Comment: Could you post your code for handling the message in Android?

Comment: I do exactly as this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Firebase API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table5) the response you get is the expected response for a successfully queued message.

The fact that you get back a `message_id` has this meaning:

> The topic message ID when FCM has successfully received the request and will attempt to deliver to all subscribed devices.

It looks like your code is working, i.e. the problem must be somewhere else.

**EDIT:**
You are sending a **data** message. (Because no `notification` key, just a `data` key) Perhaps your client expects a **notification** message instead?

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for the distinction between those two message types.

You can try and just add a notification key to the request:

```ruby
fcm = FCM.new(FIREBASE_API_KEY, :timeout => 30)
options = {:notification => "Test notification", 
           :data => {:message => "This is a FCM Topic Message!"}}
response = fcm.send_to_topic('global', options)
```

Comment: My Android client App can receive notification when sending by PHP code. But cannot with above Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem before

try to add `priority: "high"` and `notification: "your message"`

in your FCM class instatiation options

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is due to changes in FCM itself but using the syntax from the gem's documentation or using the format from Daniel's answer did not work for me (Daniel's version gives an error response from FCM saying that notification must be a JSON object).

This is what worked for me:

```
fcm.send_to_topic(topic, notification: { body: "topic notification" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the fcm library does not provide support to the rubies < 2.0. According to the git history of the repository that was the case already at the [start](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/blob/v0.0.1/fcm.gemspec) of the project.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 request = HTTParty.post('http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', :body => { "to" => "#{token}", "priority" => "high", "data" => { "title" =>title,"body"=>message,'massage_type'=>'text'}}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "key=#{server_token}" } )
```